# Прикрепление файла и текста при отправке через интент

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Когда я шарю файл по почте или мессенджером, я хочу добавлять к нему сообщение. Для этого есть интент:

```
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
            putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ArrayList(uris)
            )
            subject?.let {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
            }
            body?.let {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body)
            }
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            type = "text/html"
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getString(title)))
```

При отправке по почте все окей: файл прикрепляется, тело и тема письма создаются. Но при использовании мессенджера (телеграм, вотсап) отправляется только файл без сообщения. Возможно ли это пофиксить?

У меня есть подозрение, что с этим ничего не сделать, т.к. такие вещи остаются на усмотрение мессенджеров, но мало ли.

Comment: попробуйте добавить Intent.EXTRA_TITLE и тип поменять на text/plain

Comment: Все равно не работает, к сожалению

Comment: а вам любой "мессенджер" подойдет для теста?

Comment: попробуйте добавить 2 типа, текст и вложение или файл через Uri передать

Comment: А как передать текст через Uri?

Comment: https://code2care.org/pages/share-image-and-text-twitter-using-your-android-application-programatically

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, но этот вариант тоже не работает.

Comment: Судя по [исходникам](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/b1aa2020e5533ea18dc77aab6c6b8236e5dc2b6c/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/LaunchActivity.java) Телеграма должно все работать, попробуйте uri и ACTION_SEND